# Get POST request body with express and fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

I'm new to server-side development.

I'm trying to set up a node.js server that can receive posts.

My client-server code sends the post request:

```js
function post(){
  fetch('/clicked', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Text'})
  })
    .then(function(response){
      if(response.ok){
        console.log('POST success.');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('POST failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And my Node.js server receives it:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.a);
  console.log(req.b);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(201);
})
```

However, my server console logs all `undefined`.

What should I do to receive my POST request body?

Comment: are you using any sort of `body-parser` in your nodejs - doesn't look like it - something like `app.use(express.json())`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting up `express.json()` inside the app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json()) 

app.post('/clicked', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.a);
  console.log(req.b);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(201);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before handling post request.

```
app.use(require('body-parser').json());
```

What body-parser does is, it will add all the information we pass to the API to the 'request.body' object.

Comment: Just a note, this would also require one to install the middleware, eg `npm install body-parser`